# Equivalent of Haskell "until" in Python

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming

Is there any built-in equivalent to [Haskell's `until`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3auntil) function in Python?

Essentially, `until` applies a function `f` to a provided starting value `v`, then applies `f` to `f(v)`, until a condition is met. In other words, `until` returns the result of repeatedly applying `f` until a condition holds.

I can implement this in Python like so:

```
def until(cond, func, starting):
    val = starting
    while not cond(val):
        val = func(val)
    return val
```

Should I use this implementation, or is there some library function I should be using instead?

Comment: I'd say I'm not trying to use a do/while loop. A do/while loop is a procedural construct that could probably be used to solve this same problem, but I don't think it's an equivalent to Haskell's `until`. Maybe that's just my inexperience with Python coming through, though.

Comment: @BlueIce Not really, he is asking about a built-in *function*, not statement.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. `itertools` has some nice tools that might be familiar from Haskell, but not one that does this. I think the while loop would be the most natural Python implementation.

Comment: A `do-while` loop will always be executed at once, so this is definitely not one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no built-in function equivalent to `until`. Python's built-in and `itertools` module has taken many things from Haskell, but not the `until` function.
Yours is also probably the simplest and most efficient way to implement it.

In fact the real problem is that there is no function that returns the results of applying a function `f` iterated, so you somehow *have* to write the `iter_apply` function to do that.

When you implement `iter_apply` it's quite easy to compose some built-in functions to obtain `until`:

```
#from itertools import ifilter as filter  # in python2

def iter_apply(func, value):
    while True:
        yield value
        value = func(value)

def until2(cond, func, starting):
    return next(filter(cond, iter_apply(func, starting)))

# or:

from itertools import dropwhile
def until3(cond, func, starting):
    iterated_values = iter_apply(func, starting)
    return next(dropwhile(lambda x: not cond(x), iterated_values))
```

Time differences:

```
In [12]: %timeit until(lambda x: x > 10000, lambda x: x+1, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.33 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit until2(lambda x: x > 10000, lambda x: x+1, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.45 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit until3(lambda x: x > 10000, lambda x: x+1, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.81 ms per loop
```

Comment: Non-lazy alternative:
`def until(p, f, x): return x if p(x) else until(p, f, f(x))`